# How to get metadata in AEM workflow?

Tags: workflow, aem

How to get metadata like Workflow Name, Workflow step, timestamp and comments in AEM wrokflow.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you interested in WorkflowModel data.
You can obtain it via workItem in execute method e.g.

```
 public void execute(WorkItem workItem, WorkflowSession workflowSession, MetaDataMap metaDataMap) throws WorkflowException {
    String title = workItem.getWorkflow().getWorkflowModel().getTitle() //Workflow Name
}
```

For more details take a look [API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/workflow/exec/WorkflowProcess.html)